# Prevent Safari 10.x from auto-downloading files?

Tags: safari

Is it possible to prevent Safari from auto downloading files? Kind of like how Firefox does it.

To be clear, I am not asking about auto-unzipping, but rather webpages that auto start downloads for nefarious dmg files.

Comment: definitive guide = done. hope you like it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To stop Safari from automatically downloading files (and instead ask you with a prompt before downloading):

1. Open Safari, and go to `Safari` -> `Preferences` in the menubar (or hit <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>)

[image: step 1 image]

2. Go to the `General` tab and hit the dropdown next to `File download location`. Choose **Ask for each download.**

[image: step 2 image]

---

Now, if I navigate to the download page for something (for example, the 1Password browser extension) and download it, a download prompt will appear before the file begins to download:

[image: download prompt]

Indeed, the file does not download until I click `Save`. If I click `Cancel`, the downloads menu shows me that Zero KB of the file was downloaded:

[image: zero kb]

Asking before each download is a great way to prevent malicious DMGs from being downloaded onto your Mac, but you can read [this great answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/263716/180636) that explains why these steps I've outlined are completely unnecessary, because DMGs can't harm your computer until you manually *install* them.

Instructions and images for Safari 10.0.1.

Comment: This is a great, clever solution to the problem. In my case, I'm not worried about whether the DMG is dangerous, but the fact that in the course of a day or a week, I'll have dozens or hundreds of unwanted DMGs which I have to manually delete and empty the trash. Just would prefer not to have to bother.